# Failed to interpolate TextStyles with different inherit values

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-getx

I have two functions of theme, **darkThemeData**, and **lightThemeData**. However, when the App is run, the theme works fine with Poppins as the default font but when I click the button to switch to **Dark mode** I get this error and the fontFamily is lost. I tried different solutions but I am stuck.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData lightThemeData = ThemeData(
      
      textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(
        Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
              bodyMedium: GoogleFonts.poppins(),
              displaySmall: GoogleFonts.poppins(),
            ),
      ),
    );

    final ThemeData darkThemeData = ThemeData(
      
      textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(
        Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
             bodyMedium: GoogleFonts.poppins(),
              displaySmall: GoogleFonts.poppins(),
            ),
      ),
    );

    return GetMaterialApp(

      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: darkmode == false ? darkThemeData : lightThemeData,
      home: navbar(),
    
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this implementation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

bool darkMode = false;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData lightThemeData = ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(
        Theme.of(context).textTheme,
      ),
    );

    final ThemeData darkThemeData = ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(
        Theme.of(context).textTheme,
      ),
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: darkMode ? darkThemeData : lightThemeData,
      home: navbar(),
    );
  }
}
```

Don't need to explicitly set the font for each text style since we use the GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme() font "Poppins" for the entire text theme.